# Converting HTML Table Containing Textboxes to HTML Table with the Textbox values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was wondering if there is an easy way to convert an html table that has textboxes as inputs into new table with the textbox values.

For example:

I have this table in which a user can insert data.

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
          <input id="name" type="text"/>
      </td>
      <td>
          <input id="phone" type="text"/>
      </td>
      <td>
          <input id="email" type="text"/>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

The user then inserts "john" into the name box, "(987)891-9819" into the phone box, and "john@email.com" into the email box.

I want my result table to look like this:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
          john
      </td>
      <td>
          (987)891-8919
      </td>
      <td>
          john@email.com
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

I am looking for a way to accomplish this in javascript / jquery.

Comment: And when is this supposed to happen, do you have a button or something in mind, or is it just supposed to happen at a magical time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually as easy as

```
$('input').replaceWith(function() {
    return this.value;
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7qsLL37q/)

Comment: "The user then inserts "john" into the name box" The inputs are alive before removing. With this code you could inject scripts to the page.

Comment: @Teemu - you could, but it doesn't matter, you could do the same thing by just opening the console.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
function convertTable() {
    $("table tr td :input:text").each(function() {
        var value = this.value;
        $(this).parent("td").empty().text(value);
    });
}
```